# PHP error undefined variable notice how to fix?

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

can somebody make sense of this? This code leaves an irritating "undefined variable" php Notice on my page. 
First I have this in my header in Wordpress. (BTW, I'm picking up another dev's code)

```
$head .= "
<link rel='profile' href='http://gmpg.org/xfn/11' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' href='".get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' )."' />
<link rel='pingback' href='".get_bloginfo( 'pingback_url' )."' />
";

ob_start();
wp_head();
$head .= ob_get_clean();
```

Then this line of code is included in a separate file.
    `<?=$head;?>` <--- What's this?

Removing this last line actually breaks parts of wordpress. I'm happy to leave it in but how do I remove the error Notice?

And what's happening in this code here? When I try to declare the $head variable like this:

```
$head = null;
```

It breaks everything..  I'm stumped. I know I need to leave it in. But I can't declare it. So php keeps up that notice. Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: where is this line of code?? `<?=$head;?>`;

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju It's included in the same file...

Comment: can you add the complete code?? i mean where you are echoing the `$head`.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju it's all in the head on this site. All of this is in the header.php file. Does that help? on this site http://www.safestoragedepot.com/blog/

Comment: Your dev is a terrible dev that doesn't conform to the [Wordpress php coding standards](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/)

Comment: what about $head = "";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `.=` so that it is assigning a value to the `$html` rather than appending to it. You cannot append `null` to a string, which is why your second attempt failed. You could initialize it to an empty string, but it's an unnecessary extra step.

```
$head = "
<link rel='profile' href='http://gmpg.org/xfn/11' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' href='".get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' )."' />
<link rel='pingback' href='".get_bloginfo( 'pingback_url' )."' />
";
```

Comment: So the site is split up into two main areas. PHP and (Wordpress Env) the Blog. I ended up assigning the html to a new variable `$html`, replacing $head with $html in the wp header. Oddly enough I ended up deleting `$head` from the php header and now everything is fine. No more Notices and Wordpress is happy too. Thanks everyone!